# Counterexample for Prime Avoidance Theorem - graded version

Tags: commutative-algebra, graded-rings

Prime Avoidance Theorem - graded version:

> Let $R$ be a graded ring and $I$ is a homogeneous ideal generated by homogeneous elements of positive degree. Let $J_1,...,J_n$ be homogeneous prime ideals such that none of them contains $I$. Then we can find $x\in I$ such that $x$ is homogeneous and $x \notin P_i\ \forall i$.

Can we find a counterexample for this theorem when $I$ isn't generated by homogeneous elements of positive degree?

Comment: Set $R=\mathbb Z_{(2)}[X]$ with $\deg X=1$, $I=(2,X)$, $p_1=(2)$ and $p_2=(X)$.

Comment: What is $Z_(2)$

Comment: Do you mean a subset of $\mathbb{Q}$ consisting $n/2^k$

Comment: No. It's the localization of $\mathbb Z$ at the prime ideal $(2)$.

Comment: I see, I'll check it